# Mean of Likert Scale Interpretation

Tags: mean, likert

When analysing Likert scale data, does our interpretation depend on the scale itself?

If for example, my scale is 1- Strongly Agree and 5 - Strongly Disagree, if my mean values for Construct X end up being for Var. A = 2.07 and for Var. B = 2.20, am I correct to interpret these results as: Variable A considers X more importantly than Variable B. Because it is closer to the "Strongly Agree" ?

Most other papers simply pick the highest mean, but I cannot do that because my scale was not designed like that. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The extent to which a person agrees does not indicate the extent to which he thinks something is important.